# Select the element with shorter name among long ones with partially same in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

So I want to select an element by class name, the problem is there are 2 elements with the same names but one of them has something in addition:

```
<div class="ads-title ads-year">
              ۱۳۹۴ -
              <span>بجنورد</span></div>

<div class="ads-title">پژو پارس ELX XUM</div>
```

The code I wrote to get ONLY 'ads-title' :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./chromedriver")
driver.get('https://mashinbank.com/%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88')
names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ads-title') 
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

But it gives me the content of both of them, my question is how to narrow it down to just 'ads-title' not included with 'ads-title ads-year' ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace that to a `css_selector` to locate only one matching node.

```
div[class='ads-title']
```

**In code :-**

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class='ads-title']") 
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

But I see with the above `css selector`, there are 15 matching nodes.

In case you are looking for **specific node** which is

```
<div class="ads-title">پژو پارس ELX XUM</div>
```

then you can use this `xpath`

```
//div[@class='ads-title' and text()='پژو پارس ELX XUM']
```

**In code :**

```
driver.get('https://mashinbank.com/%D8%AE%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%88')
names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='ads-title' and text()='پژو پارس ELX XUM']")
for name in names:
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: Thanks! 1 more thing: I chose the 'ads-color' class but its included with span: <div class="ads-color">
              سفید
              <span style="float: left;"><i class="mb-clock mx-1" style="margin-top: 2px; float: right;"></i>
                دقایقی پیش
              </span></div>                                it is possible to remove that span informatin? cause I wanna save the color of all images without than span info.

Comment: Do you want to make changes here `<span style="float: left;">` ?

Comment: All of the span tag info is extra and not necessary, but its in ads-color class.

Comment: hmm.. I would advise you to create a new ticket for that, since I know how to update the attributes but I'm afraid I do not know to remove them.